# Sorting a list + detecting at least 5 directly following items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a

```
List<myobject> test
```

---

myobject looks like this:

```
public string wert;
public string symbol;
```

---

which contains those values for *wert*

```
14
13
13
12
5
5
4
4
3
```

or

```
14
4
4
5
13
3
13
5
12
```

or more or less other numbers.

Goal is to sort it. I did this by

```
var temp = from mmm in test
           orderby Convert.ToInt16(mmm.wert) descending select mmm;
```

Then I want to find whether there's a line of at least 5 elements that directly follow each other. By that I mean for instance:

```
1-2-3-4-5
```

So the difference between each element should be 1.

I used

```
myobject vorher = null;
int anzahleins = 0;
foreach (var kl in temp)
{
    if (vorher != null)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(vorher.wert) - Convert.ToInt16(kl.wert) == 1)
            anzahleins++;
    }
    vorher = kl;
}

if (anzahleins >= 4)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

But this returned

```
14
13
13
12
5
5
4
4
3
```

As true aswell, because it is

```
14
13
12
5
4
3
```

And it fulfills the condition 4 times. But it should only do that if all are directly following each other.

What would Linq say?

Answer (score 1):

You should reset anzahleins when the difference isn't 1. And you should do the check (==4) in the foreach loop. Now it just checks if there are atleast four random matches.

```
bool _flag = false;

foreach (var kl in temp)
{
    if (vorher != null)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(vorher.wert) - Convert.ToInt16(kl.wert) == 1)
        {
            anzahleins++;
        }
        else anzahleins = 0;

        if (anzahleins >= 4) _flag = true;
    }
    vorher = kl;
}

return _flag
```

This should give the result you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyObject> test = new List<MyObject>();
// populate test
var sorted = test.OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt16(x.Wert)).ToList();

bool flag = false;
int count = 0;
short lastValue = short.MaxValue;
foreach (short wert in sorted.Select(x => Convert.ToInt16(x.Wert)))
{
    if (wert - lastValue == 1)
        count++;
    else
        count = 0;

    if (count == 4)
    {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
    lastValue = wert;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing here?

Comment: "sorted" is "test" sorted by its wert property.  
"flag" is true if if there are five consecutive werts.